# how to pass useContext data without jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following logic written outside of jsx in React:

## parent

```
export const dataUseContext = React.createContext("default");
...
const someData = {}
someData["name"] = "john"
someData["age"] = 33

<dataUseContext.Provider value={someData} />
```

## child

```
const dataResponse = React.useContext(dataUseContext)
console.log(dataResponse)
```

the approach above returned by the `console.log` is empty, is there something that i am missing on how to pass the using useContext without using `jsx`?

Comment: Is the child wrapped by the `dataUseContext.Provider` component?

Comment: Here's a minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-jones-o12njm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @AdamThomas the problem that i am facing is to wrap the child while making a variable of that child so i can use it to process data, if you have a written solution to show me, that would be helpful

Comment: "making a variable of that child" means you are rendering dynamic children? Please clarify. Also, not sure how this is relevant tbh, as long as the child calls the useContext hook, it can read the data. I updated the sandbox with a dynamic child.

Comment: @ChrisG yes, i just meant the data passed from the parent to the child component is being assigned as a variable

Comment: What does that mean? Data is passed to direct children via props, assigning those to variables is not necessary usually. Or do you mean a variable is passed as prop? And what does that have to do with how contexts are used...? Sorry, I don't follow at all.

Comment: @ChrisG I know, in my case, I do need to use that way

Comment: I think you need to describe the situation in which @ChrisG codesandbox doesnt work for you -- i think its all you need